# Construct set with list comprehension via function call only if not None

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Having the call

```
set(self.oid_to_path(oid, entries_parents) for oid in modified_by_one_parent_oids)
```

this works, but also adds `None` to the list if the function returns `None`

So modifying it to

```
set(self.oid_to_path(oid, entries_parents) for oid in modified_by_one_parent_oids if None != self.oid_to_path(oid, entries_parents))
```

also works, without the `None`s.

However this has the drawback of calling the function twice. How to call it only once, and use some memoization instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a set comprehension on a generator expression...

```
g = (self.oid_to_path(oid, entries_parents) for oid in modified_by_one_parent_oids)
result = {el for el in g if el is not None}
```

Please note that you don't actually have a list comprehension in your code. You're calling the `set` constructor with a generator expression, which can be done simpler – with a set comprehension, as shown above.